# Meteor Unable to upload an image

Tags: mongodb, collections, upload, meteor

Hello I'm new on Meteor and try to develop a simple file/image upload / download.

My code and packages:

```
meteor create testApp
meteor add cfs:standard-packages
meteor add cfs:filesystem
```

**testApp.js**:

```
   YourFileCollection = new FS.Collection("yourFileCollection", {
            stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("yourFileCollection", {path: "~/meteor_uploads"})]
        });
if (Meteor.isClient) {
      // counter starts at 0
    Template.yourTemplate.events({
        'change .your-upload-class': function(event, template) {
            FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
                var yourFile = new FS.File(file);
                yourFile.creatorId = Meteor.userId(); // add custom data
                YourFileCollection.insert(yourFile, function (err, fileObj) {
                    if (!err) {
                       // do callback stuff
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        YourFileCollection.allow({
            insert: function (userId, doc) {
                return !!userId;
            },
            update: function (userId, doc) {
                return doc.creatorId == userId
            },
            download: function (userId, doc) {
                return doc.creatorId == userId
            }
        });
    }
```

and html:

```
    <head>
  <title>protoSonn</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> yourTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="yourTemplate">
    <input class="your-upload-class" type="file">
</template>
```

have also two images in my /testApp/public folder. 
After i select an image in my public folder and click ok. Nothing happends. No collection created in mongodb nothing. whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First i see you are not authentication using accounts package and you are unnecessary including the `Meteor.userId()` into you collection and second you have allow/deny rules, which will not work obvivious due to not inclusion of accounts package

First/ Simple solution : 
Remove following lines from code

```
yourFile.creatorId = Meteor.userId(); // add custom data
```

and allow/ deny rules

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
        YourFileCollection.allow({
            insert: function (userId, doc) {
                return !!userId;
            },
            update: function (userId, doc) {
                return doc.creatorId == userId
            },
            download: function (userId, doc) {
                return doc.creatorId == userId
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is working code at meteor pad : http://bit.ly/1u8gpOq
After upload, in dev console check for file with following command-

```
YourFileCollection.find().fetch()
```

Second solution:

Include Authentication to your app with accounts package so, that you will get Meteor.userId() some value and show the upload screen after that